# Creating Private Root CA using AWS CLI (acm-pca)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-acm

I have been trying to setup a private Root CA using the ACM-PCA CLI and I can't get it working.

After creating the certificate authority via

`aws acm-pca create-certificate-authority --certificate-authority-configuration file://ca.txt --certificate-authority-type "ROOT" --idempotency-token 98256344`

I keep getting stuck in the *PENDING_CERTIFICATE* state and I can't find a way for signing the CA CSR and installing the CA certificate using the CLI. The documentation only tells me how to do it using the Console.
Does anyone have an idea what I could do?

Tobias

Answer (score 2):

Through trial and error I discovered that the [description in the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm-pca/latest/userguide/PCACertInstall.html#InstallRoot) is what is needed:

- Get the CA's CSR
- Issue a certificate using that CSR and the public template
- Import the newly issued certificate

This gist shows example Go code: https://gist.github.com/ewbankkit/e2cc73d707318ae7cbba29b3cfe3fb4c.